Как в tmux вводить команды в консоль tmux через bash
Какой командой из bash можно выполнить, допустим, команду "set-option -g -q mouse on" в сессии ses2 окна win4? То есть какой командой сделать следующее:сначала нажать Ctrl-b, потом :, потом ввести set-option -g -q mouse on и нажать Enter?
#Подготовка сессии
tmux new-session -d -s ses2 -n win4
tmux attach-session -t ses2
#Примерная ожидаемая команда (не работает это)
tmux send-keys -t ses2:win4 C-b : "set-option -g -q mouse on" ENTER
Или есть ли способ временные конфиги подсовывать tmux, которые будут работать только в данной сессии и без перезагрузки tmux?

очень похоже на ошибку xy
